# 'Matrix' object has no attribute 'profile_set'

Tags: python, django

I have been struggling with this problem for an hour. I have searched everywhere but I can't find a solution to this. Maybe my problem is different. Will you kindly help me figure out whats wrong. I am stuck

```
class Matrix(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    count = models.IntegerField()

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    level = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    #Parent matrix
    parentmatrix = models.ForeignKey(Matrix, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='parentmatrix')
    #Child matrix
    childmatrix = models.ForeignKey(Matrix, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='childmatrix')
```

Here is my profile view  code

```
def profile(request):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)

    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    children = user_profile.childmatrix.profile_set.all()

    context = {
        'user':user,
        'user_profile': user_profile
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

I am developing a multi level marketing system. I want to list users that have joined under another user. So I am trying to link a user profile to a **matrix** which the user belongs to. Like in the code a user belongs to a **parent matrix** and a user owns a **matrix**.

Comment: Explain what you are going to achieve?

Comment: I am building a multi level marketing system, I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify a `related_name` then Django will not create the `_set` attribute on your Matrix model. Instead the `related_name` will be use to create the lookup attribute.
In your case the Matrix model instances will have `parentmatrix` and `childmatrix` attributes that can be used to get the related Profile instances.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly setting the related_names of the `parentmatrix`/`childmatrix` foreign keys to `parentmatrix` and `childmatrix`.

That is, they will appear on `Matrix` *too* as `parentmatrix` and `childmatrix`, and they will be querysets of `Matrix`es.

In general, if you have foreign keys (that is, 1:N relations), the related names should be somehow plural, and with `OneToOneField` relations, they should be singular.

So notwithstanding your business logic (what *are* parent and child matrices?), I'd recommend e.g.

```py
parent_matrix = models.ForeignKey(
    Matrix,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='profiles_as_parent',
)
child_matrix = models.ForeignKey(
    Matrix,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='profiles_as_child',
)
```

and you will be able to query all profiles that have a given Matrix as a parent via e.g.

```py
mtx = Matrix(...)
mtx.profiles_as_parent.all()
```